# i don't know why chrome.downloads.download function is undefined in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I was making my chrome extension app.
that is downloader program.
so, i write 'permissions: ["downloads"]'for using download function in manifest.json.
but, i can't use functions relevant to downloads..

i posted works below,

```
//manifest.json
{
    "manifest_version" : 3,
    "name" : "downloader",
    "version" : "0.0.1",
    "description" : "sample",
    "permissions" : ["downloads"],
    "content_scripts" : [
        {
            "matches" : ["<all_urls>"],
            "js" : ["index.js"]
        }
    ]
    
}
```

```
//index.js
chrome.downloads.download(
    {
        url: ""
    },
    function(id) {
        alert("completed");
    });
```

i can find this in console window
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'download')`

Comment: sorry,, i find the solution...
i know that downloads API can't be used in content_script
thx